# scrolling two listview android

Tags: android

I am using two listview. It is showing properly but the second listview is not visible in landscape mode. I can't use scrollview in listview.

My layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E9E0DB"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/member_80" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Hermoine"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usertype"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Basic"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/joined_on"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usertype"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Joined on Sep,21 2013"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_posts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usertype"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:text="899 Posts"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/membervotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/votes_bg"
        android:text="388"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topformline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnsettings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topformline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNotification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/notification_icon" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.8dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/messages_icon" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.8dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnprofile_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/setting_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomformline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnsettings"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center" />


                 <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bottomformline"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/follow_list_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/list_view"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to take the two listview in a single scroll. How to do that? Any suggestions please?

Thanks,

Comment: Post screenshots of portrait and landscape view.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can put these two listview in scroll view, and disable the scrolling of listviews, Now you will have single scrollview for two listviews.

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomformline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >


            <your.package.name.NestedListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <your.package.name.NestedListView
                android:id="@+id/follow_list_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</ScrollView>

    public class NestedListView extends ListView implements OnTouchListener, OnScrollListener {

        private int listViewTouchAction;
        private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;

        public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            listViewTouchAction = -1;
            setOnScrollListener(this);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    scrollBy(0, -1);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            int newHeight = 0;
            final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
                if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                    int listPosition = 0;
                    for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                            && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                        //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup){
                            listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        }
                        listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                        newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                    }
                    newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
                }
                if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                    if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                        newHeight = heightSize;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    scrollBy(0, 1);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```